# transitionX moves text away from the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-transitions, jsx

I have side menu and a content page. When side menu is visible, it 'moves' all the content to the right. But the part of the content that was already on the right of the page moves away from the screen (I want it to behave just like if the width of the container decreased)

The working example: 
https://arturtakoev.github.io/redux-reader/
If you check one of the boxes and then move the menu away you can see 'time created' at the right, but if moves outside of the screen if you open the menu.

```
/* Container */
.content {
    transition: transform .5s;
    padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}

.visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
}
/*Posts*/
.title {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 350;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.info {
    opacity: 0.54;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

JSX for the app:

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <SideMenu onClick={this.handleSelectSource.bind(this)}
                onSelectAll={this.handleSelectAll.bind(this)}
                onUnselectAll={this.handleUnselectAll.bind(this)}
            />
        </div>

        <div className={`${styles.content} ${toggleMenu.isVisible ? styles.visible : styles.hidden}`}>
            <div class={styles.hamburger} onClick={this.handleToggle.bind(this)} className={toggleMenu.isVisible ? styles.change : ''}>
                <div class={`${styles.bar1}`}></div>
                <div class={`${styles.bar2}`}></div>
                <div class={`${styles.bar3}`}></div>
            </div>

            {isEmpty === true ?

                <div className={styles.info}>
                    Select source
                    </div>

                : (posts.length === 0 ?
                    <div className={styles.info}>
                        <img src={require('../assets/loading.svg')} />
                    </div>
                    : <div ><Posts posts={posts} /></div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

And for the content (posts)

```
<div>
    <ul className={`list-group list-group-flush`}>
        {posts.map((post, i) =>

            <a href={post.url} target="_blank" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" key={i}>
                <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <p className={styles.title}>{post.title}</p>
                </div>
                <div className={`${styles.info}`}>
                    <small>{post.site}</small>
                    <small>{time_ago(post.created)}</small>
                </div>
            </a>
        )}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by setting the width of `.content` when it has the `.visible` class, i.e. when the `sidebar` is open, to `width: calc(100% - 250px)`.

Add the following entry to your CSS:

```
.content {
    transition: transform .5s;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}    

.content.visible {
    width: calc(100% - 250px)
}
```

When the sidebar opens, it translates `.content`, `250px` to the right, forcing it off the screen. By setting the above property, you are making it so that `.content`'s total width is `100% - 250px` (i.e. screen width **minus** the width of the sidebar), hence it won't move out of the screen.

Comment: it worked! do you know any way to animate this width change (
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out; doesn't work). and now the text disappears and appears in another place.

Comment: The reason your transition is not working is because there is no default `width` set on `.content`. If you set it to have an initial width then it will animate between the two values. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Also worked. although the change of width animation is very laggy in Safari (chrome is ok)